# Any distros already using Plasma 5 (February 2015)?

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, version, plasma

I heard that in April Kubuntu 15.04-stable will use [Plasma 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Plasma_5). I have tried it in Kubuntu 15.04 beta version, but a lot of existing KDE tools are available that don't fit Plasma 5.

Are there any distros that already use Plasma 5 desktop in a stable version?

Comment: KaOS and Netrunner 15 currently

Answer (score 1):

Plasma 5.2 is out and it is considered a stable version. Of course there are still things to iron out, and most plasmoids and some programs are not ported yet.

AFAIK no distro is using it by default yet. You can easily install it in Arch, Kubuntu etc. I've tried both those (I'm a long standing Arch user) and for now the Kubuntu implementation seems more complete.
Still, for a 100% rock solid system I'd stay with KDE4 for a while longer and wait for 5.3 or 5.4, even with 5.2 there are still things to fix. However, its already usable right now if you accept a couple of glitches. I find it OK on my secondary system, on my primary I'll stick with KDE4 for a while longer.

By the way, it's awesome.

Comment: I have it also on Kubuntu and can confirm what you say. The glitches can be severe for the moment - like the one that upgrading after installation uninstalls basic parts of the system, namely the window manager (`kwin`) which has to be re-installed manually. - From what I see it is considered stable, but on the other hand **it seems odd that it cannot be independently installed on a system that doesn't already have KDE 4 installed. Why is that?** - It seems dependent on and also in conflict with some KDE4 parts.

Comment: @cipricus I've not had any issues so far as severe as those you report, which are to be addressed by Kubuntu's packaging team, not KDE's. I find that, like with most transactions, for the end user the best policy is to keep some versions back. Enthusiasts and wannabe-testers will find that 5.2 is mature enough to be used and bugged enough to provide some entertainment bug reporting and fixing stuff. That said, compared to the transactions to KDE4 and Gnome3 it was sublimely free of severe issues.

Comment: I like it so much myself that I will keep it installed and upgrade as it goes. Problems come from Kubuntu 15.04 not being stable either yet. But from my experience it works better than Plasma5 installed on top of 14.10. As for my question, I guess Kubuntu 15.04 in April 2015 will be the first stable release to use Plasma 5 .

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't stable a versions of Plasma 5 available yet (I think it's still a work in progress).

Arch Linux for example, has preliminary support for Plasma 5, but as of now there are still some issues. If you want, you can read [the entry in their wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Plasma) about it, for more information.

In their forum, there is also a [very active topic](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184439&p=24).